# concatenating UNIX files on Mainframe

Tags: unix, concatenation, mainframe

I am using BPXBATCH to concatenate an unknown number of files to 1 single file, then porting the single file to the mainframe;  The files are VB: The files append after the last byte of previous file and I would like to append new file at beginning of new record on the Single file
What Data looks like:

```
File1BDT253748593725623.....File2BDT253748593725623.......
...............File3BDT253748593725623....
```

Here is what I would like it to look like:

```
File1BDT253748593725623.....
File2BDT253748593725623.......
...............
File3BDT253748593....
725623
```

Here is the BPXBATCH SH command I am using.

```
BPXBATCH SH cat /u/icm/comq/tmp1/rdq40.img.bin* > + 
/u/icm/comq/tmp1/rdq40.img.all
```

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you getting the file to the Mainframe?

Comment: After I concatenate(Stack) the files I am using IKJEFT01 do an "OGET" on the concatenated dataset to a mainframe DSN

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like:

SH for f in /u/icm/comq/tmp1/rdq40.img.bin* ; do cat $f >> /u/icm/comq/tmp1/rdq40.img.all ; done

you can also copy your file to an MVS Sequential Dataset with the following syntax "//'RDQ40.IMG.ALL'". Not all shell commands understand it. cp and mv does.

Comment: Can you explain how that would produce different output, please?